# Проблемы с ios. Unity3d

Tags: ios, unity3d

Есть приложение для мобильных устройств. На android все работает хорошо, но на Ios при открытии первой сцены (сцена главного меню, где есть только ui кнопочки и их анимации), фпс находится в районе 15-20. И так продолжается до тех пор, пока не будет открыта вторая игровая сцена, тут уже все работает плавно. И после выхода из второй сцены обратно в главное меню, все работает очень плавно. С чем может быть связано такое поведения приложения?

Comment: Прикрепите, пожалуйста, скриншоты содержимого "проблемной сцены" (желательно отдельно: состояние при первом запуске и состояние при возврате к сцене). Ну и подробности по коду не помешают...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему. Во второй игровой сцене у меня стояло Application.targetFrameRate = 60, а в первой этого не было вообще. Видимо на ios по умолчанию ставится не очень большое значение в районе 20. После того, как добавил в первую сцену Application.targetFrameRate все стало плавно)

Comment: 60 фпс много для мобильных устройств, пожалейте аккумуляторы и окружающую среду